# Is there any router setting that does the ssh domain forwarding?

Tags: ssh, domain, router

Is there any router setting that does the ssh domain forwarding? Currently I have one static IP and have multiple machine under it and I have multiple domains point to same IP and each domain dedicated to specific machine. So I just want to access those machine via ssh.

abc.com --> 192.168.1.10

bcd.com --> 192.168.1.11

dbc.com --> 192.168.1.12

I know that we can access the web requests using proxy or load balancer but how can we access through ssh console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set daemons to listen on different ports. Then forward ports to each server accordingly. Use:

```
ssh -p port_number external_IP
```

to connect to them.